# Volley HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch: Unable to parse dateStr: -1, falling back to 0

Tags: android, networking, android-volley

I have this error when using volley

> HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch: Unable to parse dateStr: -1, falling back to 0
>
> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "-1"
>           at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(HttpHeaderParser.java:135)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(HttpHeaderParser.java:97)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:86)
>           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:143)
>           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
>           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)

Everything's work fine but i see this error in logs for every request. What is this and how can i solve the error ?

I tried many ways and there is error in all of them. For example :

```java
val url = "http://...."

val params = HashMap<String, String>()
params["parameter"] = "value"

val parameters = JSONObject(params)

val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, parameters,
    Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
        Log.d("result", response .toString())
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { error ->
        Log.e("result", error.toString())
    })

VolleyService.requestQueue.add(request)
```

Comment: can you solve your problem?

Comment: In android ... No. But i can solve this from server by changing headers @Ak23

Answer (score 3):

it comes form expires try to replace it:

```
    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
     // Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
      try {
        loading.dismiss();
        String expire =response.headers.get("expires");
        String date=response.headers.get("Date");
        if(expire.length()<3){
          response.headers.put("expires",date);
        }

      } catch (Exception e) {

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is just ignore this log because it was spammed due to expire header response from server

for more check the below links

https://github.com/google/volley/issues/223

https://github.com/google/volley/issues/282

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be replacing the String in the header Treemap in the response:

```
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String parsed;
    try {
        if(charset != null) {
            parsed = new String(response.data, charset);
        } else {
            parsed = new String(response.data, 
HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        parsed = new String(response.data);
    }
    String regexedStr = regexed(response.headers.get("Date"));
    response.headers.put("Date",regexedStr);
    return Response.success(parsed, 
HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}

public String regexed(String str){

    String LV= "([a-zA-Z]{1,3}) ([a-zA-Z]{1,3}) (\\d\\d) (\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d) (\\d\\d\\d\\d)";
    str = str.replaceAll(LV,"$1, $3 $2 $5 $4 GMT");

    return str;
}
```

This formats the usual Date from

TUE FEB 11 11:28:17 2020

to

TUE, 11 FEB 2020 11:28:17 GMT

Since regex in java is general bad solution and the Volley error doesnt really stop the task, I would suggest running this code only in your personal Debug mode.